# Go Gin: Pass Zap Logger

Tags: go, go-gin, go-zap

I'm working in a project using Gin and recently started implementing a logger through the project. I saw a couple libraries but decided to go with uber's Zap.

I've got controllers that look like this:

```
package controllers

func ListAllArtists(c *gin.Context) {
    db := c.MustGet("db").(*gorm.DB)
    service := services.NewArtistService(db)
    pagination := entities.PaginationFromRequest(c)
    err := service.FindAll(pagination)
    if err != nil {
        err := c.AbortWithError(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print(err)
        }
        return
    }

    responses.RespondPaginated(c, pagination, service.Artists)
}
```

as you can see they call a service which performs a DB call. So the only parameter the service receives (in this case) is the db connection.

Routes are defined as following:

```
func ArtistRoutes(router *gin.RouterGroup) {
    artistRouter := router.Group("/artists")
    {
        artistRouter.POST("", controllers.CreateNewArtist)
        artistRouter.GET("", controllers.ListAllArtists)
        artistRouter.GET("/search", controllers.SearchArtists)
        artistRouter.GET("/slug/:slug", controllers.GetArtistBySlug)
        artistRouter.GET("/:id", controllers.GetArtistById)
        artistRouter.DELETE("/:id", controllers.DeleteArtistById)
        artistRouter.PATCH("/:id", controllers.UpdateArtist)
    }
}
```

My `main` file looks like:

```
app := core.NewApp()
    if app == nil {
        log.Fatal("app could not be initialized. Shutting down")
    }

    // initialize middlewares.
    app.Router.Use(func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Set("db", app.Db)
    })

    // serve static files. All static files (images, videos, css, js, etc) will be served from this location.
    app.Router.Static("/assets", "./assets")

    // Initialize all api routes
    routes.InitializeRoutes(app.Router.Group("/api/v1"))
```

My question is: is there a way to pass down the logger? can I make it part of `c *gin.Context` so it's widely available?

I'm aware of an option that `zap` offers in which you can make the logger global, but that's not recommended (although my project is pretty small) so I wouldn't want to go that route.

Comment: Yes, making the logger context-scoped is a great idea: while `zap` tries to maintain immutability, it isn't really guaranteed. And at some point you even might want to pass request-specific logging tags e.g. for auditing - at the last then you'll need to pass it anyway. `gin.Context` comes with methods like `Set()`, `Value()` and `Get()` where you can pass and receive a logger. You're already using `Set()`. I'ld recommend to use a `string` constant though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using already the `Get` and `Set` methods provided by `gin`, but thought there was a different approach in which I could make the logger part of the context directly without having to invoke it via `Get`.

Comment: sorry, regarding my previous comment, lemme clarify that I'm using them for the DB connection

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best way but it is what I ended doing (at the moment, waiting for a more suitable response to implement):

Created a `logger.go` file in my `utils` package:

```
package utils

import "go.uber.org/zap"

var Logger *zap.Logger

func InitializeLogger() {
    Logger, _ = zap.NewProduction()
}
```

then in my main I initialized the logger:

```
utils.InitializeLogger()
```

and using the logger throughout the project like:

```
func CreateNewArtist(c *gin.Context) {
    db := c.MustGet("db").(*gorm.DB)
    service := services.NewArtistService(db)

    utils.Logger.Info("Creating new artist")

    body := forms.AddArtistForm{}

    utils.Logger.Info("Request body")
    utils.Logger.Info(body.Name)
    // getting request's body
    if err := c.BindJSON(&body); err != nil {
        responses.RespondWithErrors(c, http.StatusBadRequest, err)
        return
    }

    artist, err := service.Save(body)
    if err != nil {
        responses.RespondWithErrors(c, http.StatusBadRequest, err)
        return
    }

    responses.RespondSuccess(c, artist)
}
```

Comment: Why not using the `Context`, though? I think this solution does the opposite of what you where trying to achive, b/c now you ended up with a global logger.